# Rails 3, generate migration with foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

How I can do or generate a migration with a foreign key? I have `municipios` table, and I want to relate with the table `ciudades`, the table will have these fields: `nombre_id` (name id), `nombre` (name), `departamento` (department) in this case how I can run the scaffold script to generate the foreign key migration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that you want to create the migration file the command is

`rails generate migration NAME [field:type field:type] [options]`

or shortcut

`rails g migration NAME [field:type field:type] [options]`

But if you want to create a scaffold from model that referencing other model. Maybe you could do it like this

create ciudades model with scaffold

```
rails g scaffold ciudades nombre_id:integer nombre:integer departamento:string
```

create municipios model that reference ciudades

```
rails g scaffold municipios ciudades:references
```

this will create attribute ciudades_id on the municipios table. 
The migration should look like this.

```
class CreateMunicipios < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :municipios do |t|
      t.references :ciudades

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :municipios
  end
end
```

also on the municipios model it will create the `belongs_to` relation.

but this does not update the `cuidades` model. You have to specify the relation.

Also keep in mind that rails automatically create id field on a model. it is the convention. if you mean that nombre_id is the primary key, you have to specify it your self.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold will not create the relationships for you. It will create views, controllers and others but the rest (relationships) need to be coded by hand.

So you scaffold "municipios", but if you want municipio has many ciudades, you need to do it yourself. For example:

When scaffold gives you:

```
<% form_for([@municipio]) do |f| %>
```

You need to change it to:

```
<% form_for([@municipio, @ciudad]) do |f| %>
```